# ¿Cómo poder emitir por pantalla una imagen usando HTML y Flask?

Tags: html, python, python-3.x, flask, jupyter

Tengo una imagen en una carpeta local y quiero poder ejecutar el script de flask y que al clicar sobre la ruta /image que llama al HTML donde se ubica la imagen la muestre por pantalla, que hasta ahora no lo hace.

La ruta en Flask es la siguiente:

```py
    @app.route('/image')
    def image():
        return render_template('fotos.html')
```

Y el HTML al que llama es el siguiente:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Foto</title>
    </head>
    <pre>
        <body style="background-color: #00AFD2; font-style: akkurat; text-align: center; font-size: 20px;">
            <h1>Foto</h1>
            <img src="C:/images/721-8953.mp4_frame65.jpg" width="500px">
            <br><a href="/volver">Volver a la pantalla de inicio</a>
        </body>
    </pre>
</html>
```

Comment: Para el atributo `src` deberías de usar la función `url_for` y colocar tus imágenes en una carpeta dentro de tu proyecto llamado `assets` o `imagenes` o lo que tu quieras